# Skipping activity when going back

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I have an app that has a menu(A),the menu has options B and C. from the menu I got to B, which has a list. When I choose from that list, it always takes me to D and from D you go to E. C does the same thing, C has another list, that takes you to screen D and then to E. the problem is that on B when I go to D and then E when I want to go back E takes me to B instead of D, but in C it works like it should. So to clear things up B and C go to the same Activity and do the same thing after wards, but for some reason E behaves differently when I go back with the action bar, but not with the back button.

any help? I've looked but found nothing.

Comment: Do you use the NavUtils.navigateUpTo() for the 'Up' Button in the ActionBar?

Comment: I remember I used it at first but I can't seen to find it anywhere, I must have deleted it, so no im not

Comment: Maybe the Activity is recreated without an Intent or State when you press the Up Button. Also you can check if there are any flags on your intent which clears or sets Activity States.

Comment: but then why does the other one work fine?

Comment: Can you post code from Activity B/C?

Comment: there is a lot of it, do you want me to post the intents?

Comment: FIXED IT, the problem was in the AndroidManifest.xml, the parent of E was set for B, so I guess since in C there was no B it just went back like it should but for B it went back to B

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! In the AndroidManifest.xml, the parent of E was set as B, so I guess since in C there was no B it just went back like it should but for B it went back to B